# Get Time In and Time Out from two rows in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, rows

```
 VriHistoryID OccurredAt              VriHistoryEventID InitiatorID
    ------------ ----------------------- ----------------- -----------
633          2013-01-01 07:41:10.567 8                 6
636          2013-01-14 11:52:34.373 7                 4
637          2013-01-14 11:52:41.780 8                 4
638          2013-01-14 12:17:12.300 7                 4
639          2013-01-14 12:17:23.207 8                 4
640          2013-01-14 12:39:55.803 7                 4
641          2013-01-14 12:55:58.003 7                 4
642          2013-01-14 12:56:47.360 8                 4
643          2013-01-14 13:43:20.453 8                 4
644          2013-01-14 16:46:19.143 7                 38
645          2013-01-14 16:47:05.397 8                 38
646          2013-01-14 17:16:30.253 7                 38
647          2013-01-14 17:17:27.193 8                 38
648          2013-01-14 17:17:47.897 7                 38
649          2013-01-14 17:23:04.640 8                 38
650          2013-01-14 17:24:40.250 7                 38
651          2013-01-14 17:25:23.360 8                 38
654          2013-01-14 21:57:56.403 7                 5
656          2013-01-14 21:59:04.280 8                 5
659          2013-01-15 04:13:38.783 7                 38
660          2013-01-15 04:14:03.283 8                 38
661          2013-01-15 02:59:26.977 7                 3
662          2013-01-15 03:00:35.840 8                 3
663          2013-01-15 03:08:01.693 7                 39
664          2013-01-15 03:08:26.023 8                 39
665          2013-01-15 03:12:49.013 7                 39
666          2013-01-15 03:13:46.000 8                 39
668          2013-01-14 23:36:23.880 8                 40
669          2013-01-14 23:40:01.337 7                 40
672          2013-01-14 23:40:39.150 8                 40
677          2013-01-15 04:35:12.970 7                 3
678          2013-01-15 02:36:52.707 7                 5
697          2013-01-15 02:53:16.810 8                 5
698          2013-01-15 02:54:07.107 7                 5
700          2013-01-15 04:58:22.440 8                 3
703          2013-01-15 05:22:49.480 7                 3
705          2013-01-15 05:44:43.357 8                 3
706          2013-01-15 05:47:26.487 7                 3
707          2013-01-15 05:47:42.597 8                 3
708          2013-01-15 03:54:52.840 8                 5
709          2013-01-15 03:55:38.920 7                 5
711          2013-01-15 05:55:44.000 8                 5
712          2013-01-15 03:56:37.687 7                 5
714          2013-01-15 03:56:43.920 8                 5
715          2013-01-15 04:10:54.820 7                 5
717          2013-01-15 04:11:08.443 8                 5
718          2013-01-15 04:12:32.947 7                 5
720          2013-01-15 04:12:38.743 8                 5
721          2013-01-15 04:15:47.843 7                 5
723          2013-01-15 04:15:54.640 8                 5
724          2013-01-15 06:20:12.350 7                 3
725          2013-01-15 06:20:38.193 8                 3
726          2013-01-15 04:20:46.910 7                 5
728          2013-01-15 04:20:49.897 8                 5
729          2013-01-15 06:15:14.463 7                 5
731          2013-01-15 10:32:13.537 7                 38
732          2013-01-15 11:10:14.990 7                 38
733          2013-01-15 11:10:25.913 8                 38
738          2013-01-15 11:24:29.533 8                 38
739          2013-01-15 11:26:28.020 7                 38
741          2013-01-15 11:36:24.213 8                 38
742          2013-01-15 11:43:19.457 7                 38
743          2013-01-15 11:44:49.100 8                 38
761          2013-01-15 13:09:51.080 7                 4
762          2013-01-15 13:10:04.207 8                 4
763          2013-01-15 13:10:21.690 7                 3
764          2013-01-15 13:12:08.617 8                 3
765          2013-01-15 13:13:25.163 7                 3
766          2013-01-15 13:14:49.400 8                 3
767          2013-01-15 13:17:20.230 7                 3
768          2013-01-15 13:17:43.467 8                 3
771          2013-01-15 14:58:25.400 7                 3
774          2013-01-15 13:18:37.350 8                 5
779          2013-01-15 20:28:59.957 7                 5
```

I have a Column occuredAt which hold Login with VriHistoryEventID  = 7 and LogOut with VriHistoryEventID=8  Values now , I want to make a query which can  select data group by InitiatorID then by Date with Login and Log out in same row

Thank you

row

Comment: Have a look here and improve your question accordingly http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Your desired results don't match the sample data.  This confuses the question.

Comment: Look at HistoryID 640-643. The sequence of events is Login, Login, Logout, Logout. But which logout goes with which login? It looks like it could be either first login/first logout, second login/second logout or first login/second logout, second login, first logout. Either possibility seems to be equally probable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012+:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      D DATETIME ,
      E INT ,
      I INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, '2012-08-23 03:28:32.000', 8, NULL ),
        ( 4, '2012-08-24 03:47:19.640', 8, 5 ),
        ( 5, '2012-08-24 03:47:50.170', 7, 5 ),
        ( 7, '2012-08-24 03:48:05.407', 8, 5 ),
        ( 8, '2012-08-29 04:09:07.120', 7, 11 ),
        ( 9, '2012-08-29 04:09:38.433', 8, 11 ),
        ( 10, '2012-08-29 04:35:32.580', 7, 11 ),
        ( 11, '2012-08-29 05:14:26.110', 7, 5 ),
        ( 13, '2012-08-29 05:14:58.877', 8, 5 ),
        ( 14, '2012-08-29 22:29:04.290', 7, 9 );


WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        CAST(D AS DATE) AS dt ,
                        ( CASE WHEN FIRST_VALUE(E) OVER ( PARTITION BY I,
                                                          CAST(D AS DATE) ORDER BY D ) = 7
                               THEN 0
                               ELSE 1
                          END
                          + ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY I,
                                                CAST(D AS DATE) ORDER BY D ) )
                        % 2 AS rn
               FROM     @t
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        SUM(rn) OVER ( PARTITION BY I, dt ORDER BY D ) AS s
               FROM     cte1
             ),
        cte3
          AS ( SELECT   dt ,
                        I ,
                        s ,
                        MIN(D) AS MIND ,
                        MAX(D) AS MAXD ,
                        MIN(E) AS MINE ,
                        MAX(E) AS MAXE
               FROM     cte2
               GROUP BY dt ,
                        I ,
                        s
             )
    SELECT  I AS InitiatorID ,
            dt AS Date ,
            CASE MINE
              WHEN 7
              THEN CAST(DATEPART(hh, MIND) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + ':'
                   + CAST(DATEPART(mi, MIND) AS NVARCHAR(2))
              ELSE NULL
            END AS InTime ,
            CASE MAXE
              WHEN 8
              THEN CAST(DATEPART(hh, MAXD) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + ':'
                   + CAST(DATEPART(mi, MAXD) AS NVARCHAR(2))
              ELSE NULL
            END AS OutTime
    FROM    cte3
    ORDER BY I ,
            dt ,
            s
```

Output:

```
InitiatorID Date        InTime  OutTime
NULL        2012-08-23  NULL    3:28
5           2012-08-24  NULL    3:47
5           2012-08-24  3:47    3:48
5           2012-08-29  5:14    5:14
9           2012-08-29  22:29   NULL
11          2012-08-29  4:9     4:9
11          2012-08-29  4:35    NULL
```

Comment: This code saved me hours of work! thank you.

One minor change is required though, if the minutes or hour is less than 10 it does not format the time properly (as you can see in the time column) to fix this replace : CAST(DATEPART(hh, MIND) AS NVARCHAR(2)) with CAST(FORMAT(DATEPART(hh, MIND),'00) AS NVARCHAR(2)) and do this for all the dateparts

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
SELECT InitiatorID,
MAX(CASE WHEN VriHistoryEventID = 7 THEN OccurredAt ELSE NULL END) [Login],
MAX(CASE WHEN VriHistoryEventID = 8 THEN OccurredAt ELSE NULL END) [Logout]
FROM @table
GROUP BY InitiatorID,CONVERT(DATE,OccurredAt)
```

**EDIT 2**
This query will show multiple login and logouts in a day

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    VriHistoryID INT,
    OccurredAt DATETIME,
    VriHistoryEventID INT,
    InitiatorID INT
)
INSERT INTO @table values(1,'2012-08-23 03:28:32.000',8,NULL)
INSERT INTO @table values(4,'2012-08-24 03:47:19.640',8,5)
INSERT INTO @table values(5,'2012-08-24 03:47:50.170',7,5)
INSERT INTO @table values(7,'2012-08-24 03:48:05.407',8,5)

;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT
    InitiatorID,
    VriHistoryEventID,
    (CASE WHEN VriHistoryEventID = 7 THEN OccurredAt ELSE NULL END) [Login],
    (CASE WHEN VriHistoryEventID = 8 THEN OccurredAt ELSE NULL END) [Logout],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY InitiatorID,VriHistoryEventID ORDER BY OccurredAt) rn
FROM @table
)
SELECT InitiatorID,MIN(Login) Login,MIN(Logout) Logout
FROM CTE C1
GROUP BY InitiatorID,rn
ORDER BY InitiatorID,rn
```

**EDIT 3** Updated the sample SQL as per updated output expected.
See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ae81/1)

```
CREATE TABLE #table
(
    VriHistoryID INT,
    OccurredAt DATETIME,
    VriHistoryEventID INT,
    InitiatorID INT
)
INSERT INTO #table values(1,'2012-08-23 03:28:32.000',8,NULL)
INSERT INTO #table values(4,'2012-08-24 03:47:19.640',8,5)
INSERT INTO #table values(5,'2012-08-24 03:47:50.170',7,5)
INSERT INTO #table values(7,'2012-08-24 03:48:05.407',8,5)

;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT
    InitiatorID,
    VriHistoryEventID,
    CONVERT(DATE,OccurredAt) OccurredDate,
    (CASE WHEN VriHistoryEventID = 7 THEN OccurredAt ELSE NULL END) [Login],
    (CASE WHEN VriHistoryEventID = 8 THEN OccurredAt ELSE NULL END) [Logout],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY InitiatorID,CONVERT(DATE,OccurredAt), VriHistoryEventID ORDER BY OccurredAt) rn
FROM #table
)
SELECT InitiatorID,OccurredDate ,LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([Login]),114),5) Login,LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN([Logout]),114),5) Logout
FROM CTE C1
GROUP BY InitiatorID,OccurredDate,rn
ORDER BY InitiatorID,OccurredDate,rn
```

Comment: there are multiple login and logout on same day , how can we differentiate that  too by a single initiator

Comment: @MuhammadAsadullah - Please could you show example results for what you would like to be returned?

Comment: @ughai - You probably want `MIN()` for the `[Login]`.

Comment: @MatBailie updated the code for multiple login and logouts for a initiator for a day

Comment: I have replaced your code with and change the insert statement  but the output is very strange Time in and Time out are not matching  INSERT INTO @table 
SELECT VriHistoryID , OccurredAt , VriHistoryEventID ,InitiatorID FROM vriHistory

Comment: Login and LogOut Dates are not same in the result

Comment: @MuhammadAsadullah - use the code after Edit 3 for updated output or check SQL Fiddle